# multiple enumerators on a tree

Tags: c#, enumerator

I have a tree variable. The first level1 has a list of level2 elements. Each of level2 has a list of level3 elements. until level4.

I nedd to iterate through level4 (all level4, like if level1 has a list), so I create an enumerator in level1. It works well. But now, I need to iterate Level2 and level3 too. I try to create 2 more enumerators in level1 class, but I get an error in the generic function

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
```

I try to use 3 IEnumerable for level1 class. But I read lots of topics that say it's not a good work.
These say to use composition. But (if I well understand), I don't have 2 lists in level1 class, but child lists in childs lists in ...

The tree can change often (a level3 can change from one level2 to another. User can add/remove elements at any level). So I can't easily store each level elements in level1 class.

The question is : what the best way to do something like that

```
foreach(level2 lvl2 in level1)
{}
foreach(level3 lvl3 in level1)
{}
foreach(level4 lvl4 in level1)
{}
```

Edit :

the tree :

```
level1
  |-> level2 node
     |-> level3 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> ...
     |-> level3 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> ...
     |-> level3 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> ...
     |-> ...
  |-> level2 node
     |-> level3 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> ...
     |-> level3 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> ...
     |-> ...
  |-> level2 node
     |-> level3 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> ...
     |-> level3 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> level4 node
          |-> ...
     |-> ...
  |-> ...
```

My tree class

```
public class TreeLevel1 : IEnumerable
{
    public list<TreeLevel2> treeLevel2 = new list<TreeLevel2>();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }
    public TreeLevel4Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new TreeLevel4Enumerator();
    }
}
public class TreeLevel2
{
    public List<TreeLevel3> treeLevel3 = new List<TreeLevel3>();
}
public class TreeLevel3
{
    public List<TreeLevel4> treeLevel4 = new List<TreeLevel4>();
}
public class TreeLevel4
{
    //some stuff
}
```

The enumerator class do a BFS and return only level4. So I can do :

```
TreeLevel1 lvl1 = new TreeLevel1();
//populate lvl1.treeLevel2 - with lots of TreeLevel2
//populate lvl1.treeLevel2.treeLevel3 - for each treeLevel2
//populate lvl1.treeLevel2.treeLevel3.treeLevel4 - foreach treeLevel3
foreach(Level4 lvl4 in lvl1)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Now I need to iterate through lvl1.treeLevel2 and lvl1.treeLevel2.treeLevel3. So I create 2 enumerators in TreeLevel1 class by adding

```
public TreeLevel2Enumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new TreeLevel2Enumerator();
}
public TreeLevel3Enumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return new TreeLevel3Enumerator();
}
```

And then use

```
foreach(Level2 lvl2 in lvl1)
{
  //do stuff
}
foreach(Level3 lvl3 in lvl1)
{
  //do stuff
}
foreach(Level4 lvl4 in lvl1)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

But I get an error in the generic enumerator in TreeLevel1 class

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator(); //error here
}
```

I understand that the program can't choose which enumerator to use. And so my question is : how can I create enumerator-like functions to iterate through each level (using a foreach would be great, but any other possibility is ok)

Comment: lookup `breadth-first search`

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ideone.com/ozdyB0) will help. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I don't explain what I really want.
In fact, I already use a BFS to iterate through level 4, with a enumerator.
What I need is 2 other enumerators for level2 and level3. I edit my questions to develop

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a very simple way to do that : yield !

I create 3 methods

```
public class TreeLevel1
{
    public IEnumerable<TreeLevel2> TreeLevel2Enumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < treeLevel2List.Count; i++)
        {
            yield return treeLevel2List[i];
        }
        yield break;
    }
    public IEnumerable<TreeLevel3> TreeLevel3Enumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < treeLevel2List.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeLevel2 lvl2=treeLevel2List[i];
            for(int j =0; j<lvl2.treeLevel3List.Count; j++)
            { 
                yield return lvl2.treeLevel3List[j];
            }
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

And now I can do that

```
TreeLevel1 lvl1 = new TreeLevel1();
//populate lists
foreach(TreeLevel2 lvl2 in lvl1.TreeLevel2Enumerator())
{
    //do stuff
}
foreach(TreeLevel3 lvl3 in lvl1.TreeLevel3Enumerator())
{
    //do stuff
}
```